# Example 10.32 Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

> **Example $10.32$**
>
> For $0\leq u\leq \pi,0\leq v\leq 2\pi$,define
>   $$\Sigma(u,v)=(\sin u \cos v, \sin u \sin v, \cos u)$$
>   The $\Sigma$ is a $2$-surface in $\Bbb R^3$ whose parameter domain is a rectangle $D\subset \Bbb R^2$ and whose range is unit sphere in $\Bbb R^3$. Its boundary is 
>   $$\partial \Sigma =\Sigma (\partial D) = \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 + \gamma_3 +\gamma_4$$
>   where $\gamma_1(u)=\Sigma(u,0)=(\sin u,0,\cos u)$
>
> $\gamma_2(v)=\Sigma(\pi,v)=(0,0,-1)$
>
> $\gamma_3(u)=\Sigma(\pi-u,2\pi)=(\sin,0,-\cos u)$
>
> $\gamma_4(v)=\Sigma(0,2\pi -v)=(0,0,1)$

My question is how do we get $\gamma_1$ to $\gamma_4$? I don't understand.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just substitute the four sides of the domain rectangle (namely: $(u,0)$, $(\pi,v)$, $(\pi-u,2\pi)$, $(0,2\pi-v)$) into the surface.

The $\pi-u$ and $2\pi-v$ are chosen so that the boundary of the rectangle is covered continuously.

Comment: Can we generalize this case? Suppose the parameter domain $D$ is not rectangle but in arbitrary shape, can we still substitute its boundary into the surface?

Answer (score 1):

$\gamma_1$ through $\gamma_4$ come from the boundary of the rectangle. The rectangle's boundary consists of four edges:

1. from $(0,0)$ to $(\pi,0)$
2. from $(\pi,0)$ to $(\pi,2\pi)$
3. from $(\pi,2\pi)$ to $(0,2\pi)$
4. from $(0,2\pi)$ to $(0,0)$

Edges 3 and 4 are traversed backwards which is why, for instance, you have $\Sigma(\pi - u,2\pi)$ instead of $\Sigma(u,2\pi)$.