# Baby rudin example 10.32

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, affine-geometry, simplex

This is the definition which we need for this example :
[image].

There is the example:
[image]

I don't understand why is $\partial\Sigma$ equal to $\Sigma(\partial D)$ and then why is $\Sigma$($\partial D$) equal of $\gamma_1 +  \gamma_2 +  \gamma_3  +  \gamma_4$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3505816/995003